# XLS0414 XAML - Severity

Tags: xamarin

Basically instead of just having my loginpageviewmodel be located in my viewmodels folder, I put it nested inside a startup folder inside the viewmodels folder so I am wondering how to update that reference here: viewModels:LoginPageViewModel', So that I do not get the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the file path is `ViewModels`-->`StartUp`-->`LoginViewModel.cs`.

Then you can add a namespace on your page:

```
xmlns:startup="clr-namespace:YourAppName.ViewModels.StartUp"
```

Just as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:startup="clr-namespace:YourAppName.ViewModels.StartUp"
             x:Class="YourAppName.LoginPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <startup:LoginViewModel></startup:LoginViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to First Page!"
                VerticalOptions="Start" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```